# Using HttpURLConnection in Android gives 403 Error

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am brand new to Android. Just trying to make a simple GET request.
Here is my code. Mostly taken directly from [enter link description here]
What am I doing wrong?

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.beckysolomon.ravelry" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
        package com.beckysolomon.ravelry;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;


        public class MainActivity extends Activity {



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            //TextView result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.results);
            new RequestActivity(this).execute("www.google.com");

        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
```

**RequestActivity.java**

```
    package com.beckysolomon.ravelry;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.Reader;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;

    /**
     * Created by beckysolomon on 11/22/15.
     *
     * Help from :
     * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android
     * http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html
     */
    class RequestActivity extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        Activity activity;
        String DEBUG_TAG = "becky";

        public RequestActivity(Activity activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
            try {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, urls[0]);
                return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
            }
        }

        // Given a URL, establishes an HttpUrlConnection and retrieves
    // the web page content as a InputStream, which it returns as
    // a string.
        private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
            InputStream is = null;
            // Only display the first 500 characters of the retrieved
            // web page content.
            int len = 500;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(myurl);
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, myurl);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                // Starts the query
                conn.connect();
                int response = conn.getResponseCode();
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "The response is: " + response);
                is = conn.getInputStream();

                // Convert the InputStream into a string
                String contentAsString = readIt(is, len);
                return contentAsString;

                // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
                // finished using it.
            } finally {
                if (is != null) {
                    is.close();
                }
            }
        }

        public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException {
            Reader reader = null;
            reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
            char[] buffer = new char[len];
            reader.read(buffer);
            return new String(buffer);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String backgroundResult) {
            super.onPostExecute(backgroundResult);

            TextView response = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.results);
            response.setText(backgroundResult);

        }
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your above code is not working because you haven't mention Protocol for your url try to use `https://www.google.com` instead of `www.google.com`.

Comment: Thanks! That was an easy fix!